# Regex for not ending with specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have a regex which matches the following -

```
/drama/uk
/drama/uk/
/drama/us
/drama/us/
/drama/fr
/drama/fr/
```

but should not match the following -

```
/drama/uk-uk
/drama/uk-uk/
/drama/us-us
/drama/us-us/
/drama/fr-fr
/drama/fr-fr/
```

So far I have managed to get the first par working like this

```
/\/drama\/\uk|uk\/|us|us\/|it|it\/|fr|fr\/$/
```

But I don't know how to get the second part working. Can any one help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an anchor to start the string `^`, then match `/drama/` and use an alternation with a non capturing group to list all the alternatives.

The slash at the end can be optional.

```
^\/drama\/(?:uk|us|fr)\/?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KLLOz1/1)